# DateTime переменную внести в ДБ

Tags: mysql, .net, c++-cli

Есть переменная DateTime^ date, нужно внести её значение в базу данных MYSQL в формате yyyy-MM-dd HH:ss:mm , как конвертировать значение в данный формат?
C++ cli

```
INSERT INTO bank.transactions (id_transaction,send_date) VALUES ( null,  '"+date+"')",conDataBaseForTransaction);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что Вы используете для роботы с базой?

Comment: Не надо заносить дату-время в виде строки. В большинстве СУБД есть тип [datetime](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) или что-то наподобие - его и используйте.

Comment: Покажите скрипт создания таблицы. | Ради всего святого - используйте [параметры](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-parameters.html).

Comment: Ради всего святого я и так использую datetime , таблица уже создана - скрипта нет

Comment: Покажите, как создана таблица: `CREATE TABLE` и т. д. | Если в БД используется тип datetime, то зачем вам форматировать _строку_?

Comment: добавил, дело в том, что DateTime сохраняет значение в виде dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss, а ДБ требует yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

Comment: У datetime, как и у любого другого типа, есть формат _вывода_. Формат _хранения_ от него не зависит. Используйте _параметры_ и вам не нужно будет задумываться о формате.

Comment: В запросе у вас имена колонок `id_transaction, send_date`. А на скрине определения таблицы я таких имен не вижу.

Comment: я упростил запрос , вы конкретно можете ответить? в каждом ответе вы всё обобщаете параметрами

Comment: я и  спрашиваю как настроить этот формат вывода

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы пишете

```
"INSERT ... VALUES (null,  '" + date + "')"
```

то при этом у переменной `date` автоматически вызывается метод `ToString()`. То есть это равноценно следующему:

```
"INSERT ... VALUES (null,  '" + date.ToString() + "')"
```

При это тип `DateTime` форматируется в соответствии с настройками текущей культуры. То есть если на компьютере пользователя установлен русский язык, формат вывода будет один, если английский язык - формат будет другой.

Метод [DateTime.ToString](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2) имеет несколько перегрузок. Среди них принимающая строку формата. Воспользуемся ей.

Зададим формат [вручную](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
"INSERT ... VALUES (null,  '" + date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:ss:mm") + "')";
```

Есть также [стандартные](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings?view=netframework-4.7.2) форматы. Например:

```
date.ToString("s") // 2018-10-27T17:28:20
date.ToString("u") // 2018-10-27 17:28:50Z
```

Не знаю, распарсит ли такие форматы MySql.

---

А теперь главное.

Никогда не конструируйте sql-запрос с помощью склейки строк. Это чревато [sql-инъекцией](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (и позорным увольнением с клеймом профнепригодного).

Кроме того, такие запросы неэффективны, т. к. каждый раз компилируются, потому что запрос с новой датой отличается от запроса с предыдущей датой. Между тем запрос с параметрами [кэшируется](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-cache.html), потому что отличия значений параметров не берутся в расчёт.

Всегда используйте [параметризованные запросы](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)!

В итоге это должно выглядеть примерно так:

```
String ^query = L"INSERT INTO bank.transactions(id_transaction, send_date) VALUES (@id,  @date)";

MySqlCommand ^command = gcnew MySqlCommand(query, connection);

command->Parameters->Add(gcnew MySqlParameter("id", null));

MySqlParameter ^dateParam = gcnew MySqlParameter("date", MySqlType::DateTime);
dateParam->Value = date;
command->Parameters->Add(dateParam);
```

В синтаксисе могут быть ошибки, я не проверял (нет под рукой мускуля и неохота ставить провайдер). В случае чего, ищите примеры использования [MySqlParameter](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlParameter.htm).

Comment: Спасибо большое :D Это курсовой поэтому времени нет заморачиваться над валидностью кода, тем более на c++ cli :),  запросы исправлю. Хорошего дня!